# How to hide system mouse cursor? (bluetooth or OTG connect)

Tags: android, mouse, usb-otg

I am working on a game app. Like all game apps, it renders two side-by-side views. I would like to support using a bluetooth or OTG mouse in my app. So, I need to hide the normal mouse pointer.

I have done a bit of searching, but can not seem to figure out how to do this. I did find something that says Android 7.0 is getting a new API for custom pointers:

http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/06/16/android-n-gets-support-custom-mouse-pointers-via-new-api-dev-preview-4/

That's great, and would probably allow me to make a blank custom pointer.

But I need this to work on my current hardware with Android 6. And I know it's possible, because the other device does hide the mouse pointer.

Any tips or tricks to achieve this would be most welcome.